# How to add view model in a Fack HttpContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, testing, httpcontext

I need to test custom Html helper methods like `@Html.CustomLabel` and `@Html.CustomLabelFor(m=>m.UserName)`.

The first one is relatively easy. I have:

```
    public static HtmlHelper Create()
    {
        var vc = new ViewContext {HttpContext = new FakeHttpContext()};
        var html = new HtmlHelper(vc, new FakeViewDataContainer());
        return html;
    }

    private class FakeHttpContext : HttpContextBase
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<object, object> items = new Dictionary<object, object>();

        public override IDictionary Items
        {
            get { return items; }
        }
    }

    private class FakeViewDataContainer : IViewDataContainer
    {
        private ViewDataDictionary viewData = new ViewDataDictionary();
        public ViewDataDictionary ViewData
        {
            get{return viewData;}
            set { viewData = value; }
        }
    }
```

But how to write the second one? I need to inject a view model in the `HttpContext` to write a test.

```
    public static HtmlHelper Create<T>()
    {
        var vc = new ViewContext {HttpContext = new FakeHttpContext()};
        var html = new HtmlHelper(vc, new FakeViewDataContainer());
        return html;
    }
```

What should I do to include that view model `T` in the method `Create<T>`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I define the `Create<T>` method.

```
    public static HtmlHelper<T> Create<T>(T viewModel)
    {
        var vd = new ViewDataDictionary();
        vd.Model = viewModel;
        var vc = new ViewContext {HttpContext = new FakeHttpContext(), ViewData = vd};
        var html = new HtmlHelper<T>(vc, new FakeViewDataContainer());
        return html;
    }
```

To use it:

```
var html = HtmlHelperFactory.Create(new LoginInputModel());
```